# Does Windows 8 installation allow use of the on screen keyboard for entering the key?

Tags: windows-8

Some keys on my laptop are non functional, and I wanted to install Windows 8 on it.

Usually I RDP into it to use it, and I dont have an external keyboard right now, so was hoping there would be be a way to enter the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it does allow you to do it.

Started the setup and found out